# DataGrid selected item isn't showing in textbox for update in C# WPF application SQL Server base

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Code for the datagrid selection changed event - the data is being shown in the datagrid, but when we select it, it does not appear in the textboxes for update or throw exception error. Database is being added with SQL Server.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace InventoryManagment
{
    public partial class ManageProduct : Window
    {
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=F:\VisualStudio\InventoryManagment\InventoryManagment\InventoryDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand();
        InventoryDatabaseEntities db = new InventoryDatabaseEntities();

        public ManageProduct()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //var prod = from d in db.AddProductTables
            //           select new
            //           {
            //               d.ProductID,
            //               d.ProductName,
            //               d.ProductPrice,
            //               d.ProductQuantity,
            //               d.ProductCategory,
            //               d.ProductImage

            //           };
            //ProductsDataGrid.ItemsSource = prod.ToList();
        }

        private void Back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ManagerDashboard Dashboard = new ManagerDashboard();
            Dashboard.Show();
            Close();
        }

        private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
            e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
        }

        private void ProductsDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
                if (ProductsDataGrid.SelectedIndex >= 0)
                {
                    if (ProductsDataGrid.SelectedItems.Count >= 0)
                    {
                        AddProductTable d = (AddProductTable)ProductsDataGrid.SelectedItem;
                        ProductIDtxt.Text = d.ProductID;
                        ProductNametxt.Text = d.ProductName;
                        Pricetxt.Text = d.ProductPrice;
                        Quantitytxt.Text = d.ProductQuantity;
                        Categorytxt.Text = d.ProductCategory;
                        Imagetxt.Text = d.ProductImage;
                    }
                }
        }

        private void Refreshbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sqlcon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                sqlcon.Open();

            var result = from d in db.AddProductTables
                       select new
                       {
                           d.ProductID,
                           d.ProductName,
                           d.ProductPrice,
                           d.ProductQuantity,
                           d.ProductCategory,
                           d.ProductImage

                       };
            ProductsDataGrid.ItemsSource = result.ToList();
            ProductsDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
            
            sqlcon.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

> System.InvalidCastException
> HResult=0x80004002
>
> Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType1`6[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]' to type 'InventoryManagment.AddProductTable'.
>
> Source=InventoryManagment
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at InventoryManagment.ManageProduct.ProductsDataGrid_SelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) in F:\VisualStudio\InventoryManagment\InventoryManagment\ManageProduct.xaml.cs:line 66
> at System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
> at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
> at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
> at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
> at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
> at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.InvokeSelectionChanged(List`1 unselectedInfos, List`1 selectedInfos)
> at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End()
> at System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection.EndUpdateSelectedItems()
> at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.MultiSelector.EndUpdateSelectedItems()
> at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.MakeFullRowSelection(ItemInfo   info, Boolean allowsExtendSelect, Boolean allowsMinimalSelect)
> at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.HandleSelectionForCellInput(DataGridCell cell, Boolean startDragging, Boolean allowsExtendSelect, Boolean allowsMinimalSelect)
> at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.OnAnyMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.OnAnyMouseLeftButtonDownThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
> at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
> at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
> at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
> at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
> at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseDownThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
> at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
> at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
> at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
> at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
> at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
> at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
> at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
> at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
> at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
> at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
> at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
> at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
> at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
> at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
> at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
> at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
> at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
> at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
> at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
> at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
> at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
> at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
> at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
> at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
> at System.Windows.Application.Run()
> at InventoryManagment.App.Main()

This is the code where items are being added to the SQL Server database:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace InventoryManagment
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for AddProducts.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class AddProducts : Window
    {
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=F:\VisualStudio\InventoryManagment\InventoryManagment\InventoryDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand();

        InventoryDatabaseEntities db = new InventoryDatabaseEntities();
       
        public AddProducts()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ManagerDashboard Dashboard = new ManagerDashboard();
            Dashboard.Show();
            Close();
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                if (ProductNametxt.Text == "" || ProductIDtxt.Text == "" || Pricetxt.Text == "" || Quantitytxt.Text == "" || Categorytxt.Text == "")
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Product field(s) are empty!", "Adding product failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    if (sqlcon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        sqlcon.Open();

                    cm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AddProductTable (ProductName, ProductID, ProductPrice, ProductQuantity, ProductCategory, ProductImage) VALUES (@ProductName, @ProductID, @ProductPrice, @ProductQuantity, @ProductCategory, @ProductImage)", sqlcon);

                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", ProductNametxt.Text);
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", ProductIDtxt.Text);
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductPrice", Pricetxt.Text);
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductQuantity", Quantitytxt.Text);
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCategory", Categorytxt.Text);
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductImage", Imagetxt.Text);

                    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    db.SaveChanges();
                    sqlcon.Close();

                    ProductNametxt.Text = "";
                    ProductIDtxt.Text = "";
                    Pricetxt.Text = "";
                    Quantitytxt.Text = "";
                    Categorytxt.Text = "";
                    Imagetxt.Text = "";

                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Your product has been added successfully", "Addition Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                     System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    sqlcon.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
            e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have `select new`. Should probably be `select new AddProductTable`.

Comment: Side points: you must have `using` blocks on `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` to dispose them, do not cache them in field. Do not use `AttachDbFilename` instead attach your database normally